# How do I store a List<String> as a resource in Android?

Tags: android, database

I have a **database with 10,000 entries**. The database is not updated regularly, but I need to fetch data from it frequently.

One of the options I give to choose a row is a ListView with text filtering.

But the **ListView takes a few seconds to load**. This time is taken to query the database and put the results from the Cursor into a List. So I decided to **create the List whenever the database is updated** and use it everytime I want to make the ListView.

**I need pointers on how I can store the List so that I can retrieve it immediately and show the ListView.**

Any alternatives you can provide would also be appreciated.

UPDATE:

My initial code:

```
public List<String> fetchNames() {
    String[] columns={NAME_KEY};
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor namesCursor=mydb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, NAME_KEY, null);
    Log.w("1", "Got query result");
    namesCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!namesCursor.isAfterLast()){
        names.add(namesCursor.getString(0));
        namesCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    Log.w("1", "List created");
    return names;
}
```

It takes about 5 seconds between the time "Got query result" and "List created" is logged.

I modified the code to use CursorAdapter

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter fetchNames() {
    String[] columns={"_id", NAME_KEY};
    String[] from={NAME_KEY};
    int[] to={R.id.list_item_1};
    Cursor namesCursor=mydb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, NAME_KEY, null);
    Log.w("1", "Got query result");
    SimpleCursorAdapter names = new SimpleCursorAdapter(dbContext, R.layout.list_item, namesCursor, from, to);
    Log.w("1", "Returning CursorAdapter");
    return names;
}
```

The activity still takes 5 sec to load, but only after "Returning CursorAdapter" is logged.

I feel that the delay is in fetching from the cursor, which is why I wanted to store it as a quickly fetchable resource. Do correct me if I am wrong in thinking that as a string array in resources, it would load faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) that you attach to your ListView rather than extracting your data into a List? It will automatically update when the database changes, and will be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still didn't solve my problem. I have edited my question to include code and specifics. Am I doing something wrong which is taking time?
(I do not need it to update when the database changes, as database updating is rare.)

Comment: Looking back at the original question, 10,000 entries is an awful lot. If I were a user facing that many entries I think that I would find it both daunting, and potentially difficult to find what I was looking for in a list. Have you considered changing the way that you present the data to break it down in to more manageable chunks for both the OS, and your user?

Comment: Yes, I had considered that, but the main functionality for finding the right entry out of 10,000 is the ListView's filter. And that would require (I suppose) that all the entries be loaded.

Comment: So I wrote some bash scripts to generate a sample 10,000 entry string array, stored it in resources and tried to create a ListView out of it. The emulator crashed with some type of memory overflow. Since I know it's no use trying my method anymore, I'll vote your answer.
Can you suggest a method for breaking the data into more manageable chunks yet allowing the user to quickly filter the entries?

Comment: It really depends on what your data actually represents.